# Subset multi-indexed DataFrame based on multiple level 1 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi=indexed DataFrame, but I want to keep only two columns per level 1, for each of the level 0 variables (i.e. columns 'one' and 'two'). I can subset them separately, but I would like to do it together so I can keep the values side by side

Here is the DataFrame

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['bar1', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2','bar3','foo3'], ['one','two','three','two','one','four']])))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), columns=index)
```

Here is the way to subset for one column in level 1

```
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)== 'one']
# or 
df.xs('one', level=1, axis=1)

# but adding two columns within either command will not work e.g. 
df.xs(('one','two), level=1, axis=1)
```

This would be the expected output

```
         bar1        foo1       foo2         bar3
          one         two        two          one
0   -0.508272   -0.195379   0.865563     2.002205
1   -0.771565    1.360479   1.900931    -1.589277
```

Comment: you can think of `xs` selection as selecting vertically, so `('bar1', 'one')`. the solutions proferred fit in well when selecting within levels

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way using `pd.IndexSlice`:

```
idnx = pd.IndexSlice[:, ['one', 'two']]
df.loc[:, idnx]
```

Output:

```
       bar1      bar3      foo1      foo2
        one       one       two       two
0  0.589999  0.261224 -0.106588 -2.309628
1  0.646201 -0.491110  0.430724  1.027424
```

---

Another way using a little known argument, `axis`, of `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df.loc(axis=1)[:, ['one', 'two']]
```

Output:

```
       bar1      bar3      foo1      foo2
        one       one       two       two
0  0.589999  0.261224 -0.106588 -2.309628
1  0.646201 -0.491110  0.430724  1.027424
```

***NOTE:*** This argument is not listed in the documented API for pd.DataFrame.loc, but is referenced in the User Guide in MultiIndex / Advanced indexing section in the [Using Slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) paragraph about middle way down with an example.

Comment: Great tip the `axis=1` parameter of `loc`!

Answer (score 9):

We can use [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) on a specific level to create a Boolean index and select with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(['one', 'two'], level=1)]
```

`df`:

```
       bar1      foo1      foo2      bar3
        one       two       two       one
0  0.042062 -0.233098  0.620974  0.330957
1  0.524495 -0.394930  0.572631  0.499279
```

Answer (score 7):

You can `reindex` and specify the `level`.

```
df.reindex(['one', 'two'], axis=1, level=1)

       bar1      foo1      foo2      bar3
        one       two       two       one
0  0.276056  1.956400 -1.495128  1.582220
1 -0.383178  1.159138 -1.646173  0.821942
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the old fashion `get_level_values`

```
out = df.loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['one','two'])]
Out[454]: 
       bar1      foo1      foo2      bar3
        one       two       two       one
0 -0.705540 -1.175132 -0.572076 -1.549703
1  0.277905  1.789925  1.104225  0.104453
```