# Accessing multiple columns in 3d pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After constructing a 3-d pandas dataframe I have difficulty accessing only specific columns.

The scenario is as follows:

```
head = ["h1", "h2"]
cols = ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]
heads = len(cols) * [head[0]] + len(cols) * [head[1]]  # -> ['h1','h1','h1','h2','h2','h2']
no_of_rows = 4

A = np.array(heads)
B = np.array(cols * len(head))  # -> ['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_1','col_2','col_3']
C = np.array([np.zeros(no_of_rows)] * len(head) * len(cols))  # -> shape=(6, 4)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=C.T, 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(A,B)))
```

yielding

```
    h1                      h2
    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_1   col_2   col_3
0   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Now I would like to get e.g. **all** `col_1`, meaning `col_1` of `h1` and `col_1` of `h2`. The output should look like this

```
    h1      h2
    col_1   col_1   
0   0.0     0.0     
1   0.0     0.0     
2   0.0     0.0     
3   0.0     0.0
```

Any suggestions how I could access those two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `slice(None)`, as follows:

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'col_1')]
```

or use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html), as follows:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx[:, 'col_1']]
```

or simply:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'col_1']]
```

(Defining extra variable `idx` for `pd.IndexSlice` is useful as a shorthand if you are going to use `pd.IndexSlice` multiple times. )

**Result:**

```
     h1    h2
  col_1 col_1
0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0
```

You can also do it with [`.xs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) as follows:

```
df.xs('col_1', level=1, axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
    h1   h2
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0
```

Slightly different output without the repeating `col_1` column labels shown.

---

The first 2 ways support selecting multiple columns too, e.g. `['col_1', 'col_3']`:

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['col_1', 'col_3'])]
```

and also:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['col_1', 'col_3']]]
```

**Result:**

```
     h1          h2      
  col_1 col_3 col_1 col_3
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Noteworthy maybe, that if multiple columns want to be selected (e.g. `['col_1', 'col_3']`) all solution except using `.xs()` are working.

Comment: @lesem  Welcome!  Pleased to help!   Yes, the first 2 ways support a list of columns too!

Comment: You can also get fancy like [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774757/15497888) and use the axis argument to `loc`: -> `df.loc(axis=1)[:, ['col_1']]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` with [`get_level_values(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html), as your columns col1, col2, col3 are in the first level of your index:

```
>>> df.loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['col_1'])]

    h1    h2
  col_1 col_1
0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0
```

If you want to grab all columns under `h1`, you can set `get_level_values(0)`, and grab `h1`:

```
>>> df.loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(['h1'])]

    h1            
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) natively supports a `level` kwarg, can simply use `df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(['col_1'], level=1)]` based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774816/15497888)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Please continue this kind of tips, they are very useful.  +1